# A little help with a Wine shortcut

Tags: wine

I've created desktop shortcuts to some Wine (Windows) software I still have to use.

But, I couldn't get an specific one works. It is a Windows software (a multimedia visual and aural presentation of some christian hymns) that requires Adobe Air.

I installed Adobe Air and I tested it (with the web testing) and it is run so fine in my Lubuntu configuration, even the software which I'm talking about, but just from the PCManFM Folders Manager direct action.

The problem is about the desktop shortcut. It is the only one which doesn't work, so I suspect that it is something about the path we have to write into the shortcut line command, but I don't know how to fix it!

Normally, to the other Wine (Windows) software I use with desktop shortcuts, I write the following line:

```
wine c:\Program files\software folder\software name.exe
```

I suspect that, with this specific software, I need to put something related with Adobe Air. But, I don't know what, where and/or how!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
wine start "c:\Program files\software folder\software name.exe"
```

The key here is using **wine start** instead of just **wine** to launch the program.

If you think the program needs to be run from it's own directory, change the "working directory" field in your shortcut to software's location.  Example:

```
"/home/username/.wine/drive_c/Program files/software folder/"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Now it is working!!! Like the Beatles' song: "I should have to know" Hahahaha!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Can you please mark this as the "best answer"?  Thanks!